# Treat optional arguments just like -h

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

How can I tell `argparse` to treat optional arguments just like `-h`, `--help`?

**test.py**

```
def test():
    print '## This is my test'

import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='test.py')
parser.add_argument('-t', '--test', action='store_true',
                    help='Should work just like "-h", "--help"')
parser.add_argument('req',
                    help='Otherwise required')

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.test:
    test()

if args.req:
    print '## Found "req"'
```

**# python test.py -h**

```
usage: test.py [-h] [-t] req

positional arguments:
  req         Otherwise required

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -t, --test  Should work just like "-h", "--help"
```

**# python test.py -t**

```
usage: test.py [-h] [-t] req
test.py: error: too few arguments
```

**# python test.py -t test**

```
## This is my test
## Found "req"
```

**# python test.py test**

```
## Found "req"
```

I want, that if `-t`, `--test` is specified, `argparse` stop here, just like it does with `-h`, `--help`.

Comment: To clarify: it sounds like you don't want -t to work "just like -h" in that it prints a help message and exits. You want test.py to require a positional argument unless -t is passed. So `test.py` throws an exception, but `test.py foo` and `test.py -t` and `test.py -t foo` don't. Correct?

Comment: What behavior of `-h` is important?  Printing help?  Exiting right a way?  Ignoring all other arguments?

Comment: Yes, ignoring all other arguments, thus if `-t`, `--test` is specified, `argparse` should stop here, regardless if there were 1 or more positional/required arguments added to the `parser`.

Answer (score 2):

Exiting funcitonality of help is defined in `argparse._HelpAction` `__call__` method.

```
class _HelpAction(Action):
    def __init__(self,
                 option_strings,
                 dest=SUPPRESS,
                 default=SUPPRESS,
                 help=None):
        super(_HelpAction, self).__init__(
            option_strings=option_strings,
            dest=dest,
            default=default,
            nargs=0,
            help=help)

    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        parser.print_help()
        parser.exit()  # it exists here
```

You either have to use `help` action:

```
parser.add_argument('-t', '--test', action='help',
                    help='Should work just like "-h", "--help"')
```

Or create custom argparse action.

```
class MyCustomAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        print("argument found, I should exit")
        self.exit()

parser.add_argument('-t', '--test', action= MyCustomAction,
                    help='Should work just like "-h", "--help"')
```

For details on creating a custom action you may refer to [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action).

Comment: Cool solution, but why not use the official api?

Comment: @Oz123 Action class is public, and custom action class is part of docs I've linked. So while `_HelpAction` is not a public API, creating custom ones is.

Comment: I tried to avoid subclassing and writing nearly as much code as the whole program/script, just to support not too special treatment of the argument, though thank you for your opinion.

Comment: If you are afraid to subclass to achieve special behaviors you are missing half the power of Python.

Answer (score 1):

The parameters of the last positional argument is not initialized correctly to achieve what you want.

```
parser.add_argument('req', nargs='?', default="truc", help='Otherwise required')
```

Please have a look to Python documentation for further details. But basically, the `nargs='?'` provides the possibility to have optional positional arguments. But you need to provide a default value.

**#python test.py  -t**

```
## This is my test
## Found "req"
```

Z.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution, define [nargs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs):

```
parser.add_argument('req', nargs='?',
                    help='Otherwise required')
```

`?` means 0 or more.

And then exit after runing your test:

```
import sys

if args.test:
    test()
    sys.exit()
```

The complete code:

```
import sys

def test():
    print '## This is my test'

import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='test.py')
parser.add_argument('-t', '--test', action='store_true',
                    help='Should work just like "-h", "--help"')
parser.add_argument('req', nargs='?',
                    help='Otherwise required')

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.test:
    test()
    sys.exit()

if args.req:
    print '## Found "req"'
```

This outputs:

```
[8] oz123@laptop-oz:~ $ python bla.py -t
## This is my test
[9] oz123@laptop-oz:~ $ python bla.py -h
usage: test.py [-h] [-t] [req]

positional arguments:
  req         Otherwise required

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -t, --test  Should work just like "-h", "--help"
[10] oz123@laptop-oz:~ $ python bla.py bla
## Found "req"
```

### update, without sys.exit

If you remove `sys.exit()`, then the output is like your wished behavior.

```
[12] oz123@laptop-oz:~ $ python bla.py -t bla
## This is my test
## Found "req"
[13] oz123@laptop-oz:~ $ python bla.py -t 
## This is my test
```

Comment: The down side of this method is that required arguments now are listed in the square brackets - `[req]`. Though they still appear in the `positional arguments` list, which indicates that they are required...

Comment: Anything is square brackets is indeed optional. You question specified `treat optional like -h`. So, This solution makes `req` indeed option, but also `-t`. As `-h` exists, I also added the exit. If this is not something you wish, just remove that line.